# Placing charset in the JavaScript file doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have such a problem. My script doesn't load external file properly.
An error is: func() is not defined. And the code:

external.js:

```
@charset "UTF-8"; 
function func(){
alert("0ddd");
}
```

and the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
<h1 align="center">My site</h2>
<script>func()</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My files are placed in the same folder. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript file shouldn't contain such character. Remove it and will work fine:

```
@charset "UTF-8"; // remove it
```

Also, you may place the script inside the body rather:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
<h1 align="center">My site</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<script>func()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to explicitly set the `charset`, then add it in the script tag itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

But it is better to provide `charset` in the meta tag: (Place the following inside the `<head>`

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```